# Set background colour on android bitmap xml

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable

I have a bitmap resource in my resources folder:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:antialias="true"
            android:tileMode="clamp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
```

when this is added to the page it adds a black background color. is it possible to either remove this and allow transparency or set a background colour by hex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting drawable defined in XML as view's background in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203641/setting-drawable-defined-in-xml-as-views-background-in-android)

Comment: As Emdja said, why not using `ImageView` instead of `bitmap`?

Comment: because im trying to work with an image, not a control

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set an extra background to set a bitmap transparent.
Your issue could be your logo itself.

Please check, if your image is transparent or your background of the page isn't black.

Comment: The logo png is definitely transparent background